# R dplyr mutate columns relative to other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = rep(1,5), z = 0:4, 
                 fx = NA_real_, fy = NA_real_, fz = NA_real_)
my_count_columns <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

I want to fill in information by mutating in place columns `fx`, `fy`, `fz` that represents the frequency of each count variable.

What is the cleanest way to do this in dplyr/tidyverse, assuming I don't know the column names ahead of time?

Expected output:

```
  x y z         fx  fy  fz
1 1 1 0 0.06666667 0.2 0.0
2 2 1 1 0.13333333 0.2 0.1
3 3 1 2 0.20000000 0.2 0.2
4 4 1 3 0.26666667 0.2 0.3
5 5 1 4 0.33333333 0.2 0.4
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: @tmfmnk added 12345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, this could be

```
df[paste0('f', my_count_columns)] <- lapply(my_count_columns, 
   function(x) sapply(df[[x]], function(y) 
       mean(y == df[setdiff(my_count_columns, x)])))
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    select(all_of(my_count_columns)) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~  map_dbl(., function(x)
      mean(x == df[setdiff(my_count_columns, cur_column())])), 
          .names = 'f{.col}'))
```

Comment: Close, can you generalize the add_count operation?

Comment: It's not quite what what I was looking for. See the edit in the original post.

Comment: That absolutely works, but I was wondering if there's a tidyverse-like approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prop.table` to get the proportions for all  `my_count_columns`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(all_of(my_count_columns), prop.table, .names = 'f{col}'))

#  x y z         fx  fy  fz
#1 1 1 0 0.06666667 0.2 0.0
#2 2 1 1 0.13333333 0.2 0.1
#3 3 1 2 0.20000000 0.2 0.2
#4 4 1 3 0.26666667 0.2 0.3
#5 5 1 4 0.33333333 0.2 0.4
```